# Avoid docker exec zombie processes when connecting to containers via bash

Tags: docker, docker-engine

Like most docker users, I periodically need to connect to a running container and execute various arbitrary commands via bash.

I'm using 17.06-CE with an ubuntu 16.04 image, and as far as I understand, the only way to do this without installing ssh into the container is via `docker exec -it <container_name> bash`

However, [as is well-documented](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/9098#issuecomment-312152980), for each bash shell process you generate, you leave a zombie process behind when your connection is interrupted. If you connect to your container often, you end up with 1000s of idle shells -a most undesirable outcome!

How can I ensure these zombie shell processes are killed upon disconnection -as they would be over ssh?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to make sure the linux `init` process runs in your container.
In recent versions of docker there is an `--init` [option](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#options) to `docker run` that should do this. This uses [tini](https://github.com/krallin/tini) to run `init` which can also be used in previous versions.

Another option is something like the [phusion-baseimage](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker)  project that provides a base docker image with this capability and many others (might be overkill).